# Permissions to see all users products, not just the orders on UberCart

Tags: ubercart

I am trying to figure out what permission in ubercart to set that would allow a user to see just the products they put in.  It show them orders but not a list of their own items. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The permission manage products must be turned off. The permission for to create a product, edit and delete own product must be turned on.